# "An Invalid IP Address was specified" Error shows up when I type an External IP c#

Tags: c#, networking, external, local

```
    Socket sck;
    EndPoint epLocal, epRemote;
    byte[] buffer;

    private void Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //binding socket
        epLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textLocalIp.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textLocalPort.Text));
        sck.Bind(epLocal);
        //Connecting to remote IP
        epRemote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textRemoteIp.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textRemotePort.Text));
        sck.Connect(epRemote);
        //Listening the specific port
        buffer = new byte[1500];
        sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);
    }
```

I'm creating a "chatroom" for 2 people. If each person has the other person's IP address and port, they are able to chat with them. But it only works on the same network because if I type any IP address that isn't a Local address it shows the error "An invalid IP address was specified"
I'm not sure how to fix this issue and I'm also wondering if I would need the External and Local IP address in order for the message to be sent to the correct computer.

Comment: Are you using the socket for TCP or UDP

Comment: Im using socket

Comment: The problem might be with `IPAddress.Parse` method. This method needs the input in proper format. Can you post the IP addresses which are failing?

Comment: The IP that works is in this format "192.168.1.234"  (last 4 digits are not the actual ones) and the IP I'm trying to use is in this format "12.345.678.900". The first one is local and the second one is external.